# Solution of a equation in natural number nvolving reciprocal of prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a prime and $n$ a natural number . Solve in $\mathbb{N}$ the equation 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^k_k}=\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: Is there supposed to be an appearance of $v$ in the equation?

Comment: Perhaps $v=n$. It would make sense . . .

Comment: @Joel I have made the changes

Comment: @Shaun I cannot make out where to begin ,this seems so general for me

Comment: The case for $n=1$ is straightforward. Take a stab at the $n=2$ case with $p=2$: $$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2^2} = \frac12$$

Comment: What do you mean by $x_k$?